# android: Application crashes on toolbar overflow menu click

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I'm implementing material design to my application. I replaced native ActionBar with new android Toolbar. Menu items are added, onOptionsItemSelected works perfectly. But when I click overflow icon or item with several more menu items, the application crashes.

toolbar screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/smay4k1qwkd8amz/Screenshot_2015-05-29-11-31-55.png?dl=0

activity_main.xml

```
    ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/my_primary"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World, MyActivity"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">

    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/my_primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/my_accent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

MyActivity.java

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

menu\main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:Compat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.myapp">

    <item
            android:id="@+id/action_add"
            android:title="Add"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
            Compat:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item
            android:title="Items"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_agenda"
            Compat:showAsAction="always"
            >
        <menu>
            <item
                    android:id="@+id/action_1"
                    android:title="item1"/>
            <item
                    android:id="@+id/action_2"
                    android:title="item2"/>
        </menu>
    </item>

    <item
            android:id="@+id/action_about"
            android:title="About"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help"
            Compat:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

The following message is shown after the crash:

```
05-29 11:21:18.012  31469-31469/com.example.myapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 31469
    java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field title of type I in class Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$id; or its superclasses (declaration of 'android.support.v7.appcompat.R$id' appears in /data/app/com.example.myapp-1/base.apk)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ListMenuItemView.onFinishInflate(ListMenuItemView.java:89)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:814)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper$MenuAdapter.getView(MenuPopupHelper.java:370)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.measureContentWidth(MenuPopupHelper.java:219)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.tryShow(MenuPopupHelper.java:153)
            at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter$OpenOverflowRunnable.run(ActionMenuPresenter.java:752)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

Also I am using the last version of appcompat library. I followed tutorials, googled, but nothing is found. What is the reason of this crash? Please, help.

Answer (score 0):

Read here.. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html
You have just created menus, you haven't provided their functions. in other words, you just inflate the menus on screen, not provided the function what they will do if use clicks on it. 
To enable them you need to implement following method, for example

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle item selection
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.new_game:
        newGame();
        return true;
    case R.id.help:
        showHelp();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

in your mainActivity.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I've already written that onOptionsItemSelected works fine. I just didn't write that method in the code above. It crashes when popup menu must be created, for example when I click overflow icon.

Comment: I have personally run this project, and it is not crashing. I haven't made any changes. are you still having the same problem?

Comment: if you are having still problem .. let me know.. ill post whole project, which i have tested and running and not crashing when i click on overflow icon.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using trasitive = false ; in build.gradle then remove it